# SQL stored procedure with

Tags: sql

I want to write a stored procedure that looks like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_ExampleDate]

@MyDate DateTime,
@ApplyDate DateTime,
@SomeString varchar(6) OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE DateFrom <= MyDate
    AND DateTo >= MyDate    
END
```

If this query returns one result I want to return it. However, if it returns two results then I want to have it run an additional query looking at the ApplyDate to get a single result.

Comment: What is your 'additional query'?

Comment: And which dbms product are you using? (This syntax doesn't look like ANSI/ISO SQL.)

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If yes: please add `sql-server` tag to make this clear. If not: **what** database system is this for?

Answer (score 2):

Put the results into a temp table then check the rowcount before returning the data or something else.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_ExampleDate]

@MyDate DateTime,
@ApplyDate DateTime,
@SomeString varchar(6) OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    into #temp 
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE DateFrom <= MyDate
    AND DateTo >= MyDate    

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
        SELECT * FROM #temp 
    ELSE
        SELECT < other result set>
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

```
declare @count int
select @count=count(*) from -- your current query
```

And then

```
if (@count>1) then
-- your current SELECT
else
-- your alternative query
end
```

This is supposing you're using SQL Server. Please, add the corresponding tag in your question.